# Как вставить дату в бд?

Tags: python, django

у меня есть дата и ее необходимо вставить в бд. модель у меня такая

```
class Raspisanie(models.Model):
    date= models.DateField()
 и в представлние я пытаюсь вот таким образом вставить
new = Raspisanie(datetime.strftime('2013-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'))
        new.save();
```

но возникает ошибка 
    descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Answer (score 1):

Вы что-то странное делаете. Во-первых, как Вам написали, strftime требует дату (которая объект типа datetime.datetime) первым аргументом, а у Вас строка. Во-вторых, в поле date лучше, опять же, класть дату, а не строку. В-третьих, new это плохое название для объекта, потому что оно может оказаться зарезервированным словом (если не в Питоне, то в каком-нибудь JS точно).

Comment: и на всякий случай пишите имя свойства явно:
    
    new_record = Raspisanie(date=datetime.datetime(2013, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0))

Comment: у меня есть строка, и ее надо в бд. мне надо надо распарсить ее как то

Comment: даже вот такая команда вызывает ошибку
newss = Raspisanie(datetime.date.today())
        newss.save(); 

int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'

Comment: Вам выше написали, что хорошо бы параметры передавать явно